# Print second vowel in word in red color

Tags: bash, printing, scripts, colors, echo

How do I print the second vowel in a word in red or blue color.
Let say I execute my script called "script1" which reads a text file. 
My script should be able to print the second vowel in every word in red or blue color. If there is only one vowel, then print that in color. If there are no vowels then print the first letter in a word in color!

Comment: What is the problem: how to colour the output, or how to recognise the second vowel? (Or both?)

Comment: I have a script which reads a text file called file1.txt prints each word one by one. What I want is to print the second vowel in every word in either blue or red color. If a word contain only one vowel then print that vowel in blue or red color, if a word has no voewls at all then print the first letter in that word in blue or red color!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="./file" # change this filename according to your requirements
red=$'\e[31m'
reset=$'\e[0m'

# read single line from $filename in $line (see last "done", last line of code)
while read -r line; do 

  # loop over every single word in $line
  for word in $line; do
    vc=$(tr -cd '[aeiouAEIOU]' <<< "$word") # remove all but vowels

    case ${#vc} in                          # ${#vc}: number of vowels
      0)                                    # no vowel
        sed -E "s/^./${red}&${reset}/" <<< "$word"
        ;;
      1)                                    # one vowel
        sed -E "s/^([^aeiou]*)([aeiou]+)(.*)$/\1${red}\2${reset}\3/i" <<< "$word"
        ;;
      *)                                    # two or more vowels
        sed -E "s/^([^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(.*)$/\1${red}\2${reset}\3/i" <<< "$word"
        ;;
    esac

  done | tr "\n" " "
  echo
done < "$filename"
```

Disadvantage: You loose consecutive whitespaces and tabs in output.

---

More information: `help <command>` or `man <command>` or `info <command>`

Comment: Can you please explain how the while and for loops are working in this script so I can better understand the solution! Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've fixed a bug with consecutive vowels.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a loop which prints one word or characters from a text file one at a time. I tried to put this together so that it can work with my loop, but it does not do anything!

Comment: Here is the loop:FS=$'\n'
for j in `cat $1`;
do
        #Reads the text file in the centre of the screen
        echo "                                                       ___________________"
        echo "                                                             $j";
        echo "                                                       ___________________"
        echo "                                                                               Speed 120 wpm"
        sleep  0.5;
        clear;
done

Comment: Can you tell me where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

How about using grep to colour the match, along with some PCRE-fu? something like

```
grep --color=always -iP '\b[^aeiou\s]*[aeiou][^aeiou\s]*\K[aeiou]'
```

where

- `\b` to match a word-boundary; then
- `[^aeiou\s]*` match zero or more non-vowel, non-space characters
- `[aeiou]` to match the first vowel
- `[^aeiou\s]*` match another zero or more non-vowel, non-space characters
- `\K` to exclude all the above from the final matched expression (effectively, a *variable length lookbehind assertion*)
- finally, `[aeiou]` to match the desired second vowel

[image]

Comment: It does not completely fulfill the OP request. You need to highlight the only vowel in the word as well, and the first letter if there are no vowels.