# How to highlight second vowel from every word in a file?

Tags: scripts, sed

I am trying to highlight every second vowel in a word to the colour red. What am I doing wrong?

```
cat room.txt | sed 's:[AEIOU]:$(printf "${\e[1;30m}&${\e[0m}"):i2'
```

Ps. Sorry for making it unclear.

I would like 2nd vowel of every word highlighted in red.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print second vowel in word in red color](http://askubuntu.com/questions/599878/print-second-vowel-in-word-in-red-color)

Comment: When asking this type of question, please always show us an example of your input and your desired output. Here, you say you want the second vowel of every word but your command (even after correcting the issues pointed out by muru) will change only the second vowel of each line. Is that what you want?

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness. I would lIke second vowel of every word highlighted.

Comment: What if a word only has one vowel? What if it has more than two? Please [edit] your question and add an example of your input and the output you would like to see for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Command substitution is not performed in single quotes, you'll have to use double quotes instead.
2. `\e[1;30m` is not a variable, so you cannot do `${\e[1;30m}`.

Try:

```
sed 's:[AEIOU]:'"$(printf "\e[1;30m&\e[0m")"':i2' room.txt
```

Here, I close the single quote and then use double quotes, and then reopen the single quote.

Comment: Thanks Muru! if i want to change the colour to red and bold what would be correct colour code?

Comment: @NebelzCheez you already have set it to bold, the number for red is 31. See http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

Comment: @NebelzCheez If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness. I would lIke second vowel of every word highlighted. –  Nebelz Cheez just now   edit   delete

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand `sed`'s `s///2` construct. That won't do every second word, it will only do the second match on every line. o highlight the second vowel of each word, you need to identify words first. An easy easy way is to convert spaces to newlines, run your `sed` and then convert back again:

```
tr ' ' $'\n' < room.txt | 
    sed 's:[AEIOU]:'"$(printf "\e[1;31m&\e[0m")"':i2' | 
        tr $'\n' ' '
```

That, however, will return a string with no trailing newline. To add that, just `echo` the entire thing:

```
echo $(tr ' ' $'\n' < room.txt | 
      sed 's:[AEIOU]:'"$(printf "\e[1;31m&\e[0m")"':i2' | tr $'\n' ' ' )
```

#### Example output:

[image]